# Dashboard and Quick Links

Tags: ux-field, dashboard

I'm working on a very complex interface that's built on a combination of new and old technology (JSP and JSF). It needs a complete overhaul but that's out of the question.

On the interface dashboard there's only a system health check, in the form of a table with a couple of rows and nothing else. The rest of the interface is given as is, without any guidance or wizards. If you want to do something, you have to dig through documentation and jump through a lot of sections in the interface without any apparent order to it.

Since there's no money nor time to actually develop a proper workflow, wizards, etc., I thought of aggregating a list of most common tasks (which would have subtasks) and offering them as Quick Links on the dashboard.

So:

Quick Link 1

Quick Link 2

etc.

Clicking on whichever one would bring up a popup showing a diagram and steps of **all** the subtasks required to accomplish that specific task in the right order. Further clicking on the subtasks links would link the user directly to those particular settings so they don't have to hunt around.

**Is there anything I should think of here, did I forget something, does this sound like a reasonable solution, do you have any other ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: Include some link to a video of a screen cast performing the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these quick links on single page and want the user to remember all the sub tasks then it would be very inconvenient for the user. Rather I would suggest you to have these link on every sub task pages. When user clicks those link in the middle of completing a task he should be able to see how many tasks he has completed and how many more tasks are needed to complete the main task. Also you should be able to highlight the current sub task he is performing.
I think this should help to improve your user experience.

Comment: Good point on the user having to remember the subtasks. I thought more of something like this:

Home Page > click on Task > Get an overview of what the task includes and a numbered list of subtasks > click on on of the subtasks and a new tab opens linked to the relevant config. 

In that way the user is always rooted to the home page and doesn't loose track of where he is. 

I am very limited in terms of implementation and changes, so I'm working trying to hack a good user experience, so to speak.